# Merge multiple files with different length from folder

Tags: r

For all my files in the folder `miraligner` I would like to combine the columns as shown in my example. I would like to combine the columns c("mir","seq","mism","add","t5","t3") as rownames in the output and `"freq"` as columns from the respective input files. 
I am not sure how to do this for multiple input files

```
> setwd("~/miraligner/")
> file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.mirna")
> head(file_list)

[1] "1_JH_F12_S41.mirna"   "107_MAE_E7_S11.mirna" "108_IME_A8_S23.mirna" "109_GW_B11_S27.mirna" "111_PH_H1_S77.mirna" 
[6] "116_TH_E6_S10.mirna" 

> head(1_JH_F12_S41.mirna)
                       seq          name freq             mir start end mism   add t5  t3       s5       s3    DB
1    TGGAGTGTGATAATGGTGTTT seq_100003_x4    4  hsa-miR-122-5p    15  35 11TC     0  0   g GCTGTGGA TTTGTGTC miRNA
2 TGTAAACATCCCCGACCGGAAGCT seq_100045_x4    4  hsa-miR-30d-5p     6  29 17CT     0  0  CT TTGTTGTA GAAGCTGT miRNA
3   CTAGACTGAAGCTCCTTGAAAA seq_100048_x4    4 hsa-miR-151a-3p    47  65    0 I-AAA  0  gg CCTACTAG GAGGACAG miRNA
4   AGGCGGAGACTTGGGCAATTGC seq_100059_x4    4   hsa-miR-25-5p    14  35    0     0  0   C TGAGAGGC ATTGCTGG miRNA
5    AAACCGTTACCATTACTGAAT seq_100067_x4    4    hsa-miR-451a    17  35    0  I-AT  0 gtt AAGGAAAC AGTTTAGT miRNA
6   TGAGGTAGTAGCTTGTGCTGTT seq_10007_x24   24   hsa-let-7i-5p     6  27 12CT     0  0   0 TGGCTGAG TGTTGGTC miRNA
     precursor ambiguity
1  hsa-mir-122         1
2  hsa-mir-30d         1
3 hsa-mir-151a         1
4   hsa-mir-25         1
5 hsa-mir-451a         1
6   hsa-let-7i         1
```

output

```
ID                                                  freq_file1  freq_file2  freq_file3
hsa-miR-122-5p_TGGAGTGTGATAATGGTGTTT_11TC_0_0_g     4          2           12
hsa-miR-30d-5p_TGTAAACATCCCCGACCGGAAGCT_17CT_0_0_CT 4          12          5
```

This is my start:

```
my.list <- lapply(X = my.file.list, FUN = function(x) {
  read.table(x, colClasses = c("seq", "NULL", "NULL", "mir","NULL","NULL","mism","add","t5","t3","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL"), sep = "\t")[,1]
})
```

Comment: yes, but that came wrong out. I will delete it

Comment: If the columns can be assured of being the same in all files then start with `input <- lapply(file.list, read.table, stringsASFactors=FALSE, <and other appropriate parameters>); fullset <- do.call(rbind, input)`. Finish by pasting the desired columns and `cbind`-ing to `freq`

Comment: I did not get your last part? How to I convert the rbind into cbind format?

Comment: input works great, however when trying fullset I get this: fullset <- do.call(rbind, input)
Error in do.call(rbind, input) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function

Comment: That doesn't  make a lot of sense. `rbind` is a base function.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is the following:
read each file in a data.frame,
remove unnecessary columns,  (`x.column <- NULL`)
then use the merge functions to add the columns where needed

```
help(merge)
```

making sure of using the proper "all" parameters (i.e. do you want to keep freq from a row of the second file even if the row does not exist in your first file or not?)